# Why is angle of deviation inversely proportional to the wavelength of the incident light ray?

Tags: visible-light, dispersion

Our teacher had given us this relation but I my problem is that I'm unable to think WHY this is happening. This was taught to us in context of dispersion by a glass prism.

A hearty thanks in advance for the valuable responses.